# Issue with kendo datetime picker in google chrome, closes automatically

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have issues with the kendo ui datetimepicker under google chrome. For some reason, the control close automatically after i try to open it(see gif for reference). [datetimepicket_Error.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7AJB.gif)

Chrome Version: 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Kendo  Version: 2015.2.805.545

Code :

```html
<input id="cmpDatePicker" style="width: 250px" data-bind="kendoDateTimePicker:{ valueUpdate: 'blur', value: CompleteDate, enabled: completeDateEnabled  }, attr: {title: completeDateTooltip }" />
```

Comment: Add your code needed to replicate the problem. That will allow users to answer your question better and easier

Comment: That's a pretty old version of Kendo. Any console errors?

Comment: Hi @Granny : Thanks for replying.  Added the code, i hope this helps. Using knockout for binding the values like "CompleteDate" and   "completeDateEnabled"

Comment: @SteveGreene : Unfortunately, no console error.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue and figured out that, in my specific case, the problem was that the rectangle that kendo is trying to draw, goes out of the boundaries of the screen, due to insuffiucient page height.
Try to add some padding to your form, in order to determine if this could be your problem.
Hope this helps.